# Centering the text inside the `p tag`

Tags: html, css

Centering the text inside the `p tag`.

Below is the `code` which works perfectly when centring the text inside a `paragraph` tag. 
Can anyone explain me how does this work?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.pos_fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="pos_fixed">Some positioned text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not really understanding on what makes the `text center`?. **I am not really understanding the trick here which makes the text center**.

**Update:**

Removing `top: 0;right: 0;left: 0;` does not `center` align. My question was how does it center?.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cvaJk

How does it all combine to make it center aling?.

Comment: text-align:center; ???

Comment: If you don't understand this, you *really* need to try to learn at least the fundamentals of CSS.

Comment: Please read this before to begin something else : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets

Comment: p tag is block element....not inline element

Comment: Using `position: fixed` and `right: 0; left: 0` anchors the element to each edge of the page, forcing it to take up the full width available. `text-align: center` then aligns the text within the element.

Comment: Without right left and top, the p width is adjusted to the content. With right left and top to 0, the p is stretched so the content is align in middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same css just change

position: fixed; to

position:relative;

```
p.pos_fixed {
    position: realtive;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: How does this work? can you explain a bit.

Comment: The problem with using "fixed" positioning is that it takes the element out of flow. thus it can't be re-positioned, thats why "relative" is used to positioned as per your requirement.

Comment: My question is how position relative makes it center?

Comment: by using realtive, element is positioned relative to its normal position and when we align text to center, it will be positioned in center.

Comment: one final question, what does it mean relative to its normal position?

Comment: it means if u add property left: 20 px and right: 10px then it will align according to default position.

Comment: @UnderTaker, please ***research*** [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for yourself, don't just pester a user that's attempted to answer your question for more and more and *more* information.

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Sorry....

Answer (score 3):

In the first part of the code you are creating a style class named 'pos_fixed':

```
p.pos_fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
    color: red;
}
```

And in that class you are defining that the text will be centered with this code:

```
text-align:center;
```

And then you are applying that style class to some text:

```
<p class="pos_fixed">Some positioned text.</p>
```